# Last Pass chrome extension creating a div that blocks clicks

Tags: html, css, authentication, lastpass

When our users have Last Pass installed, after they log in they see a big div with this markup and styles:

```
<div style="position: fixed !important;z-index: 2147483647 !important;display: block !important;width: 100% !important;height: 100% !important;top: 10px !important;right: 10px !important;max-height: 182px !important;max-width: 368px !important;">
<iframe src="chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/contentScriptDialog.html?dialogID=1" scrolling="no" style="border: none !important; position: relative !important; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; visibility: visible !important;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Users are unable to click anything in our website when using Last Pass, has anyone found a solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in a website where I can not edit the styles ¿Some idea of how to hide the `div` forever in my browser?
On the other hand... I think html injection is not a safe and reliable practice of Last Pass

Answer (score 13):

Right-click on LastPass -> Manage Extension, and then change Site Access to On Click.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The website has the following style in its CSS:

```
iframe { display:none; }
```

You need to remove this and target your iframes more specifically in your code.

Comment: I don't think so